# Compilation speed slowed down from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-optimization

In Xcode 5 all was pretty good, about compiling speed.
Now, in Xcode 6.1, compiler stops at "asset catalog image_xcassetes" (I looked at compiler log) for about 35 seconds (edited form 15: I've measured it after first post), then continue regularly.

I tried cleaning, deleting image_xcassets (compiler then stops anyway but on "copying" a resource pdf file: deleting it then stop on another one ...), changing it so it is rearranged by compiler, and deleting all my .png images to see it the problem was related to new 3x images set.

Only deleting all storyboard contents is runs without stopping.

I don't figure out how to overcame this issue.

Comment: Pausing for 15 seconds seems like a trivial issue to me.

Comment: The issue is not 15 seconds. It is: why Xcode 6.1 stops in compilation process in respect of Xcode 5? Is there something related to resource management changes? Or about new config issues? Anyway think about 10 runs: it's more or less 3 min. waiting

Comment: I've just measured the real time stopping: it's 35 seconds on each run after changes in storyboard, in respect on apparently 0 seconds waiting before.